# PHP loop condition

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Although following code is for WordPress, but my question is more about general PHP loop.

I want to get posts of last 7 days. I want to get only last 7 days which have posts. If some day does not have any post, it should skip to next day.

I am using following loop to get posts from last 7 days, but the problem is that if a day does not have post, it will loop through last 7 days only, no matter if there's any post or not.

So, I have tried to extend $i value only if there is post, but if I place it inside the if condition, it will run infinite times.
Thanks for any help about this.

```
$day = date('j');
while( $i <= 7){
    query_posts('day='$day);    
    if (have_posts()){  
        //list posts.
    }   
    $i++;
    $day--;
}
```

Comment: You need to identify the case where you have checked all entries. In other words when your query fails or you go past the first(last) post.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the $day becomes negative?

Comment: @Moob this is more complicated than I thought. I want to get last 7 days which have the posts, but now I realized that day (int) is not good idea as it wont work in negative days. I'm just unable to figure out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a maximum for the loop and query by date rather than day:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$maxAttempts=100;
$postCount=0;
while( $i <= $maxAttempts && $postCount <= 7 ){
    query_posts('date='$date);    
    if (have_posts()){  
        //list posts.
        $postCount++;
    }   
    $i++;
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date .' -1 day'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$day = date('j');
$post_days_count = 0;
while( $post_days_count < 7){
    query_posts('day='$day);    
    if (have_posts()){
        $post_days_count++;
        //list posts.
    }   
    $day--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried this, this won't work because the day of the month will go into negative, and if i place $day inside the if condition, it will run infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your loop to only increment `$i` if a post was found, which would mean the loop would run until it found 7 posts. Be sure to handle the case where it can never find 7 posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes, thats what I'm trying to do. If I place the $i inside the if condition, then the $day would go in negative and the loop wont return correct results.